# Move polygon points based on center location?

Tags: turfjs

Would someone have an example using Turf moving all polygon points from one location to another based on a new center point?

For example, let’s say I have calculated a center based on where the points were originally created.

Then I need to move those points to a new location based on that calculated center.

As always any help would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [transformTranslate](http://turfjs.org/docs/#transformTranslate)

```
var poly = turf.polygon([[[0,29], [3.5,29], [2.5,32], [0,29]]]);

//calculates the centroid of the polygon
var center = turf.centroid(poly);

var from = turf.point([center.geometry.coordinates[0], center.geometry.coordinates[1]]);

var to = turf.point([4, 35]);

//finds the bearing angle between the points
var bearing = turf.rhumbBearing(from, to);

//calculates the distance between the points
var distance = turf.rhumbDistance(from, to);

//moves the polygon to the distance on the direction angle.
var translatedPoly = turf.transformTranslate(poly, distance, bearing)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for that! Can you explain what’s happening in each line?

Comment: I've fixed the code and added some comments. Please check.

Comment: Thanks man! That’s super helpful. Will this work for lines, extents, circles and ellipsis?

Comment: It should work with any geojson Feature or Geometry.

Comment: @AnatolySukhanov If I need to get the nearest Location saved in my DataBase, I'm using turf.nearestPoint, they back just **One** Point nearby in my location, How to get all the points that are about 50 km from my place